# SQL state: 42883 function sum(character varying) does not exist

Tags: sql

I am running the query

```
select distinct product.product_name, details.batch_no, details.kit_no, SUM(details.recevied_qty) Rcdqty 
from masters_productmaster product
  join inventory_grndetails details ON details.product_id_id = product.id
group by product.product_name, details.batch_no, details.kit_no;
```

getting the below error,

```
ERROR:  function sum(character varying) does not exist
LINE 1: ...duct.product_name,details.batch_no,details.kit_no,SUM(detail...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 70
```

Not getting what to do next

Comment: Please add the type of DB.

Comment: what column type is `details.recevied_qty` ? seems like it is some sort of text colum (varchar, nvarchar ...)

Comment: The error is telling you what to do: _"You might need to add explicit type casts"_ in order to cast the string field `details.recevied_qty` to a number. Something along the lines of `SUM(CAST(details.recevied_qty as INTEGER))`, depending on your DB.

Comment: Rather alter the column to a numeric data type (e.g. integer.)

Comment: No need to do SELECT DISTINCT here, it just raises many eyebrows, your GROUP BY returns no duplicates.